# Is it possible to extract certain rows from a file where the first column contains an identifier that matches the names of other files?

Tags: file, awk, sed, file-io, io

I asked this as part of a larger question yesterday. A commenter suggested splitting it off into its own question.

I have x files.  The contents of the first five files appear below.  On the second row, `i` is a counter so that `i = 0` for the first file.  Next to `i` is `time` and it always increases by 0.5 when `i` increases by 1.

However, I have only kept every xth file. So while `i = 0` for the first file that I have, `i = 100` in the second file, and so on.

```
6 # This file is called "0.xyz" (<--the "6" is the same in all files)
i =       0, time =        0.000, k =      9000000000000
X        -7.6415350292        6.0494971539        8.1919697993
Y        -6.6418362233        5.9231018862        8.4056822626
Y        -8.0518670684        6.3158684817        9.0061271154
X        26.8252967820       20.4661074967       17.8025744066
Y        26.4477411207       20.4071029058       16.9121571912
Y        26.4399648474       21.2950722068       18.1009273227

6 # This file is called "100.xyz"
i =       100, time =        50.000, k =      2500000000000
X        -6.2423192714       -1.5704681396       -9.5648670474
Y        -5.4925100813       -1.6522059045       -8.9030589772
Y        -6.7765278574       -2.3616512405       -9.4776648590
X         4.1248924594       27.8487302083      -17.5400886312
Y         4.1238657681       26.9869907778      -17.9727402579
Y         5.0750649402       28.1292768156      -17.6848507559

6 # This file is called "200.xyz"
i =       200, time =        100.000, k =      3945000000000
X        19.0090162215       -5.9338939011        6.1931167954
Y        18.4748060757       -6.4905073540        5.6656446036
Y        19.2825591449       -6.4479943255        7.0179774953
X        11.0203415273       34.6029396705        2.7220660957
Y        11.1184002007       34.8398120338        1.8089008500
Y        10.3349649622       33.9509485292        2.5605794622

6 # This file is called "300.xyz"
i =       300, time =       150.000, k =      2341000000000
X        -7.6415350292        6.0494971539        8.1919697993
Y        -6.6418362233        5.9231018862        8.4056822626
Y        -8.0518670684        6.3158684817        9.0061271154
X        26.8252967820       20.4661074967       17.8025744066
Y        26.4477411207       20.4071029058       16.9121571912
Y        26.4399648474       21.2950722068       18.1009273227

6 # This file is called "400.xyz"
i =       400, time =        200.000, k =      2500000000000
X        -6.2423192714       -1.5704681396       -9.5648670474
Y        -5.4925100813       -1.6522059045       -8.9030589772
Y        -6.7765278574       -2.3616512405       -9.4776648590
X         4.1248924594       27.8487302083      -17.5400886312
Y         4.1238657681       26.9869907778      -17.9727402579
Y         5.0750649402       28.1292768156      -17.6848507559
```

**What I would like to do is match these files (above) with data from another file (below)**.  In the file below, each row matches one file above according to the `i` (Step).  Then I would like to print the first three columns of the matching rows in the file below to a new file.

Although I have included file names, I would prefer to do the matching by using `i`, not the file names.

**I know how to do this by simple iteration**.  What is mean is, I can count and print every xth row of the file below to a new file.  However, I would like to use a more sophisticated approach that specifically matches `i` because these are very long files and there could potentially be rows missing so that I'd end up with a mismatch between the files above and the one I want here.

```
    #   Step       Time        Ax                   Ay                  Az                  Bx                  By                  Bz                  Cx                  Cy                  Cz                     Final 
           0       0.000       14.8032123290        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8032123290        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8032123290          3243.9033438318
           1       0.500       14.8029498502        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8029498502        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8029498502          3243.7307919244
           2       1.000       14.8026923814        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8026923814        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8026923814          3243.5615395313
           3       1.500       14.8024398604        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8024398604        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8024398604          3243.3955453870
           4       2.000       14.8021922354        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8021922354        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8021922354          3243.2327751298
...
           100       50.000       14.8032123290        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8032123290        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8032123290          3243.9033438318
...
           200       100.000       14.8029498502        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8029498502        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8029498502          3243.7307919244
...
           300       150.000       14.8026923814        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8026923814        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8026923814          3243.5615395313
           301       150.500       14.8024398604        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8024398604        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8024398604          3243.3955453870
...
           400       200.000       14.8021922354        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8021922354        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8021922354          3243.2327751298
```

**Example** of what I would like the result to be from manipulating the file above to match the set of example files at the top of the question:

```
   0         0.000         14.8032123290        
   100       50.000        14.8032123290
   200       100.000       14.8029498502
   300       150.000       14.8026923814
   400       200.000       14.8021922354
```

If anyone has any hints on how to approach this, I would be grateful.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: each question should stand on its own; this means sample input(s) should match with (expected) output(s) ... this isn't the case here; I'd suggest updating the question to show matching data (between inputs and outputs); alternatively, since we know the first 6 files were extracted from a single larger file (see link to previous Q&A), it may make more sense to (instead) provide a sample of the larger file and the matching (expected) output; once you find an acceptable answer you may then be able to roll these two Q&A's into a single script (to address your original 2-part requirement)

Comment: @markp-fuso, thank you.  I see what you mean and hope the question is now clearer.

Comment: at one point you state *matches ... according to the i (Step) and time* and later you state *matching by using the i or the time*; could you update the question to clarify the matching requirements ... `i *AND* time` or `i *OR* time`?

Comment: @markp-fuso, yes, I would be happy to if I can find the spot that is causing confusion.  I am paranoid, so would prefer to match i AND time, but it should be fine to match only i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `awk` script to do this as follows:

```sh
awk 'FNR == 1 {
if ($0 ~ /^i =/) {
    dataFile = 0;
    step[$3+0] = FILENAME;
}
else {dataFile = 1;}
}

dataFile == 1 && step[$1] {
    print $1, $2, $3;
}' *.xyz data.txt
```

(assumes the final file is called `data.txt`; change as necessary)

`FNR == 1` matches the first line of every file and will either capture the step from the `xyz` file, or set a flag indicating that we've reached the data file.  The `$3 + 0` bit will just force `awk` to convert the 3rd field to a number (*i.e.*, drop the trailing comma) due to the request to perform a mathematical operation.

`dataFile == 1 && step[$i]` matches lines within the data file where the step value was seen in an `xyz` file.

**NOTE**: You must specify all the `xyz` files before the final data file, so that all the steps are collected before the data file is processed.

---

Sorry, when I put the above solution together, I thought the `# This file is called` lines were not part of the file.  Modified script is here:

```sh
awk '
FNR == 2 && FILENAME != ARGV[ARGC-1] {
    step[$3+0] = FILENAME;
}

FILENAME == ARGV[ARGC-1] && step[$1] {
    print $1, $2, $3;
}' *.xyz data.txt
```

This version uses ARGV & ARGC to determine whether the "data" file is being processed.

- If not the data file and line number == 2, cache the "step" value
- If the data file, and the step is in the list, print the first 3 fields

Result:

```
0 0.000 14.8032123290
100 50.000 14.8032123290
200 100.000 14.8029498502
300 150.000 14.8026923814
400 200.000 14.8021922354
```

Comment: thanks a lot.  Awk is so much faster than Python (which I'm used to) for dealing with manipulation of huge files but I am not experienced enough to do what I sometimes need to do.  Thanks for educating me!

Comment: @markp-fuso, did you delete the first line of the .xyz files (the one with the "6" in it)?

Comment: @markp-fuso, apologies, I should have said, as you did, that the script can be modified to access the correct line.  Deleting the line has another advantage for my particular situation.  Thank you both for all your help.  My files are hundreds of thousands of lines long and having an Awk method to deal with them is so much faster and more reliable than what i was doing.

Comment: @markp-fuso: Yes, I had neglected to include the "6" line in the files.  I've updated the answer, and left the original script for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- matches are based on both `i` (aka `step`) and `time`

The `step / time / Ax` data file:

```
$ cat match.dat
    #   Step       Time        Ax                   Ay                  Az                  Bx                  By                  Bz                  Cx                  Cy                  Cz                     Final
           0       0.000       14.8032123290        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8032123290        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8032123290          3243.9033438318
           1       0.500       14.8029498502        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8029498502        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8029498502          3243.7307919244
           2       1.000       14.8026923814        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8026923814        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8026923814          3243.5615395313
           3       1.500       14.8024398604        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8024398604        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8024398604          3243.3955453870
           4       2.000       14.8021922354        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8021922354        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8021922354          3243.2327751298
           100       50.000       14.8032123290        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8032123290        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8032123290          3243.9033438318
           200       100.000       14.8029498502        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8029498502        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8029498502          3243.7307919244
           300       150.000       14.8026923814        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8026923814        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8026923814          3243.5615395313
           301       150.500       14.8024398604        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8024398604        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8024398604          3243.3955453870
           400       200.000       14.8021922354        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8021922354        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.8021922354          3243.2327751298
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR   { if (FNR>1)                        # skip header line in 1st file
               Ax[$1 OFS $2]=$3               # use step + OFS + time as index for Ax[] array
            next
          }

$1 == "i" { gsub(/,/,"")                      # remove commas from line so we can use normal FS delimiter to pull ...
            i=$3                              # field #3 (i) and ...
            time=$6                           # field #6 (time)
            if ( (i OFS time) in Ax)          # if i + OFS + time is an index in Ax[] array ...
                print i,time,Ax[i OFS time]   # print our 3 values to stdout
          }
' match.dat [0-9]*.xyz
```

This generates:

```
0 0.000 14.8032123290
100 50.000 14.8032123290
200 100.000 14.8029498502
300 150.000 14.8026923814
400 200.000 14.8021922354
```

If OP needs the output displayed with pretty columns one idea would be to pipe the results to `column`, eg:

```
$ awk '...' match.dat [0-9]*.xyz | column -t
0    0.000    14.8032123290
100  50.000   14.8032123290
200  100.000  14.8029498502
300  150.000  14.8026923814
400  200.000  14.8021922354
```

**NOTE:** this code is matching on exact matches of character strings; it is *not* matching based on numeric values; so `150 != 150.00`

Comment: great tips about the formatting and use of character strings.  Thank you for going out of your way to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '2~100s/^((\s*\S+){3}).*/\1/p' file
```

Turn on extended regexp and off implicit printing `-En`.

Starting from line 2 (the line following the header) use modulus 100 to select the required lines and then the substitution command to keep only the first three columns.

If you must use the initial file for matching, then:

```
sed -En 's/^i =\s*(\S+),.*/s#^\(\\s\*\1\(\\s\*\\S+\)\{2\}\)\.\*#\\1#p/p' file1of5 |
sed -Enf - fileWithStep
```

This generates a set of sed commands which extracts the step values and matches them against file with step values and retrieves only the first 3 columns.

N.B. The five files can be concatenated or individually named after the first set of sed commands i.e. replace `file1of5` by `file1 file2 file3 file4 file5` *if* they contain unique step values.